# Did Boris Yeltsin regret his decision of choosing Putin as his successor?

Tags: russian-federation, history, vladimir-putin

In a PBS documentary, [Putin's revenge](https://youtu.be/o2L8qINZD3Q), the following is said at around 10m15s by [Strobe Talbott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strobe_Talbott).

> Before Boris Yeltsin died, he told intimates that it was a great mistake to have selected Putin as a successor.

From narration it looks like Boris Yeltsin told the  above to his intimates at the end of his life and didn't say it publicly. But do we have any other accounts or sources that confirm Boris Yeltsin saying so? And did he said so at any other time before or publicly anywhere?

Comment: This is going to be impossible to verify as all we have is their words which will most certainly be impossible to verify through other sources at this time.

Comment: @JoeW - Yes , let's hope someone will dig more deeper and will come out with something or perhaps it's quite possible that someone will get a hint from some Russian sources like books or biographies etc.

Comment: Yelstins daughter has said something like this.

Comment: The problem is what source will those books and biographies use? If all all points back to the people he told how do you verify it?

Comment: @convert Do you have a source?

Comment: @JoeW Depending on the kind of relationship the source had with Yelstin, we can make a conclusion about how reliable the info is. Obviously, trusting some Amrerican's criticism of a Russian politician is stupid, as they will have their own vested political interests.

Comment: @sfxedit Just because someone does or doesn't have a close relation to someone doesn't validate or invalidate something that they say that person told them. I am not saying that the claim is correct or incorrect just that the ability to verify it is going to be pretty much impossible.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo Yes this is also true.

Comment: @sfxedit Have seen the interview where she was tallking abou it.

Comment: @convert No. Can you provide the link?

Comment: @sfxedit It was on TV, so the link could be problematic.

Comment: I think it is at least safe to say Putin did not turn out to be what Yeltsin expected. The original rationale for choosing Putin was that he's a quiet, unassuming, consensus candidate who won't piss off anyone in the establishment. It's the same reason Gorbachev was chosen as leader, but Putin turned out quite differently.

Answer (score 9):

According to this [article in a Russian source](https://www.rbc.ru/economics/08/12/2000/5703b2169a7947783a5a18be) he did regret the decision:

> **Yeltsin regrets that he gave power to Putin**
>
> Less than a year later, former President Yeltsin regretted handing
> over the reins of government to Putin. And, oddly enough, the reason
> for this was not some kind of foreign policy or domestic political
> mistake, but ... dissimilarity of musical tastes. According to the
> first president, "such things are not joked about." In an interview
> with Komsomolskaya Pravda, Yeltsin said that he regretted that he
> shifted responsibility for solving a number of issues to his successor
> Putin. In particular, Yeltsin was referring to the adoption of a new
> state symbol of Russia, as well as questions about the burial of
> Lenin's body and the prohibition of the Communist Party.
>
> In vain the coast, it turns out, it would have been better to do
> everything himself then," Yeltsin laments now. But what confuses him
> the most is the activities of the current president, Putin. According
> to him, Putin is becoming a symbol of the Communists. And Boris
> Nikolaevich is most upset because he "unnecessarily shifted
> responsibility to the future president." It would be better to appoint
> Chubais, Yeltsin believes, because he always speaks very correctly.
> For example, regarding the anthem, Chubais "well said that the
> president of the country should not blindly follow the mood of the
> people."

By dissimilarity of musical tastes is meaned the return of the Soviet anthem, which was banned by Yeltsin as a relic of the Stalin era.

Comment: Unlike Lukashenko's statement, this one is from 2000, when Yeltsin was still alive. And the source is rather trustworthy.

Comment: It might be surprising to know that artistic tastes are correlated to politics.

Comment: @user253751 Musical tastes is not the same as artistic tastes.

Comment: @convert music is a form of art

Comment: @user253751 Was your coment some kind of question about what was meaned by that tastes?

Comment: That doesn't sound like it is about music at all.

Comment: @haxor789 But anthem is about music.

Comment: @convert Not necessarily Yeltsin seems to have been a reformer, who split up the USSR and banned the communist party, maybe having a "fresh start"-narrative. While Putin reintroduced soviet symbolism and forwarded a narrative of the USSR as Russian history and a nationalist continuation, which he still uses as a narrative to justify his wars and annexations. So there's a good chance they did not differ in the taste of music but in the symbolism and what it symbolizes.

Comment: @haxor789 The new anthem is not exactly the old Soviet one, but the melody is exactly the same and melody is about music.

Comment: @convert A national anthem isn't just a song, it's a national symbol and depending on the country and politician choosing it can have a lot of symbolic meaning. And if you literally take the familiar melody and add a new text, that's a pretty obvious symbolism for a continuation with slight modifications rather than something new. So no that doesn't have to be about music. Could be but likely isn't.

Comment: @haxor789 So just to make it clear, there is no real disagreement between us, just need to keep in mind the quote is a translation from Russian and some things are seen diferent there.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the start , although I don't know how credible it  is , but  I Just found one article published in [runews24.ru](https://runews24.ru/eng/politics/07/08/2020/6a94f3s3732c6908d6cb3a8186c564c5)  which is shading some light on the topic.

The main focus of the article is Disagreements between Mr. Putin and Mr. Yeltsin.

It looks like that Mr Yeltsin was also not satisfied by Putin's policies.

> Putin's adviser Valentin Yumashev said that Yeltsin was dissatisfied
> with the fact that Putin had abandoned his liberal course - in
> particular in economic policy.

---

The site is referring to an interview of    [Alexander Lukashenko](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Lukashenko)

given by himself to Ukrainian journalist Dmitry Gordon (  according to the memoirs of Lukashenko).

> During an interview Alexander Lukashenko said Ukrainian journalist
> Dmitry Gordon that Russian President Boris Yeltsin regretted choosing
> Vladimir Putin as his successor.

Comment: This makes it sound like Yeltsin wanting even more empire building with power projection, whereas first Putin terms were more isolationist

Comment: It's a strange quotation - what does the maintenance of military bases have to do with liberal economic policy? Those ellipses in the middle suggest something has been missed out.

Comment: Downvoted as the edit to the quote highlight the Q&A is made in bad faith - Yeltsin didn't have any extraordinary foresight on how Putin would turn out, and as per the quote he only "regretted" appointing Putin because Putin rolled back some of Yeltsin policies and experimented with his own new policies.